# Error using strcat

Tags: c

On my school assignment i have to find a string with a brute force algorithm.

If the length is, for example , 3 these are all the possible combinations:
    a
    b
    c
    aa
    ba
    ca
    ab
    bb
    cb
    ac
    bc
    cc
    aaa
    baa
    caa
    aba
    bba
    cba
    aca
    bca
    cca
    aab
    bab
    cab
    abb
    bbb
    cbb
    acb
    bcb
    ccb
    aac
    bac
    cac
    abc
    bbc
    cbc
    acc
    bcc
    ccc

I having problems in `strcat`.

here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
# define PASS_SIZE 3


char letters[] = "abc";
char test[] = "acb";
int count = 0;
int nbletters = sizeof(letters)-1;
int bruteForce(int size);

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int notFound = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= PASS_SIZE && notFound == 1; i++){
        notFound = bruteForce(i);
    };

    printf("Count: %d\n",count);

    return -1;
}

int bruteForce(int size){
    int i;
    int entry[size];
    char pass[50];
    char *temp;

    for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
        entry[i] = 0;
    }
    do {
        for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
            temp = letters[entry[i]];
            printf("%c", temp);
            strcat(pass,temp); /*Getting error here*/
       }

        count++;
        printf("\n");

        /*Compare pass with test*/
        if (strcmp (pass,test) == 0){
            return 0;
        };

       for(i=0 ; i<size && ++entry[i] == nbletters; i++){
            entry[i] = 0;
        }

    } while(i<size);

    return 1;
}
```

Probably the brute force algorithm is not the best one.

Why isn't strcat working and I'm getting segmentation foult?

Comment: *"Why isn't strcat working?"* is a rather vague statement. Please state the exact error and behavior that you encounter.

Comment: @Zeta Sorry. Program crashes. Segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your `pass` variable but you are not initializing it. When you concatinate onto its end, you're assuming initially its end is its start, but you need to make that be the case.

More importantly, take a look at your `temp` variable. You've declared it to be a `char *`, but you've initialized it to be a `char` (instead of pointing to a char), and then in `strcat()` you treat it like a pointer again -- but it's not pointing anywhere valid (causing your crash).

Comment: Thanks but even after initialization I'm getting segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` is expecting a null-terminated string, but `char pass[50]` hasn't been initialized. Set `pass[0] = '\0'` to get a valid C string.

Comment: Thanks. Ok but making char pass[50]; pass[0] = '\0'; still getting error